# Where can I find a BRDF reference implementation?

Tags: rendering, raycasting, reflection-rendering, pbr

Does anyone have a link to a sample implementation of how to create/handle 4D BRDFs?

I found a few interesting papers and websites,

- [Szymon's (student, Princeton) BRDF survey, 1997](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~smr/cs348c-97/surveypaper.html)
- [SIGGRAPH survey](http://www.siggraph.org/publications/newsletter/volume-43-number-2/a-survey-of-brdf-models-for-computer-graphics)

but cannot seem to find any reference implementation to play with. Anyone have any?

[image: brdf]

Image from [Predicting reflectance functions from complex surfaces](http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/133994.134075)

Comment: This question is unclear to me.  There are quite a lot of different BRDF models out there; which one(s) do you want a reference implementation for?

Comment: _Any_ one, to give me an idea of how they are programmed!

Comment: nVidia's own site has an entry on SBRDF if you want source for a spatial variant on pure BRDF.  Check here: http://brdflab.sourceforge.net/ for an open source (Ogre3D based) application.

Comment: @PatrickHughes Great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are quite a few implementations of BRDFs in [pbrt](http://www.pbrt.org/), the (open-source) raytracer described by the Physically Based Rendering book.  That book is also a great reference for anyone interested in 3D graphics, even if you're not interested in raytracing.

Comment: I am interested!  Very interested.